# c# app doesnt trigger failure-restart in Windows task scheduler

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to utilize windows task scheduler restart functionality on failure of my c# app.
[image: task scheduler seetings]

However when my process fails (I have tried to return 1 and -1 on failure in the code) it doesnt trigger a restart, even though the task scheduler "Last Run Result" shows a failure code (0x1 or 0xFFFFFFFF).
Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Is your C# app .Net Framework or .Net Core? Is it a background service? Windows service? Just a windows forms app? Or something else ??